# Why does getEngineByName(“js”) return null?

Tags: java, javascript, android, javax.script

Whatever I try, `getEngineByName()` keeps returning null.

Here's my code:

```
final ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
final ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
```

But `engine` is null after these lines.

I also tried:

- `getEngineByName("javascript")`
- `getEngineByName("nashorn")`

They all return `null`. Actually, `manager.getEngineFactories()` shows an empty array - meaning there are no Factories at all.

These 2 answers suggest passing `null` to the constructor, but it didn't work for me:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25332851/900394
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25332851/900394

And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054252/trying-to-use-rhino-getenginebynamejavascript-returns-null-in-openjdk-7) says it's a bug that **has been fixed**.

---

**Update:**

That was an **Android Application Project** in eclipse.

I didn't know it differs that much from a **Java Project**.

Now I just opened a new **Java Project**, wrote these lines, and I'm getting some results:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import javax.script.SimpleBindings;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("js");
    }
}
```

`engine` isn't **null** !

Also, `javax.script.*` was imported successfully as if it's already there (built in). Is this because I'm using Java 8?

In that previous (android) project I was using **javax.script** downloaded from [here](https://code.google.com/p/jav8/).

So what would be the problem in the **Android Project** and how do I solve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10757892/4015623 See if that helps

Comment: I have [had success](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7441804/418556) with `getEngineByExtension("js")`

Comment: @AndrewThompson, Same problem...

Comment: @AlaaM. Any update on this issue?

Comment: @ShailendraMadda - Nope, I dropped the project.

Comment: @AlaaM. I tried this it's working now. 
`val jsEngine = ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("rhino")` refer this [link](https://github.com/APISENSE/rhino-android)

Answer (score 5):

You have to write the argument with Capital Letters, as shown below:

```
getEngineByName("JavaScript");
                 ^   ^
```

Comment: Even I did the same but still it is null

Answer (score 3):

Apparently when running in an IDE even if you are on a recent version of Java that includes the Nashorn javascript engine you have to pass `null` into the `ScriptEngineManager` constructor or else it often won't have engines.  It'd be fine when actually compiled, seems to be an IDE error.  For me it was resolved by changing this code:

```
mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
```

to this code:

```
mgr = new ScriptEngineManager(null);
engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
```

Note the `null` passed into the `ScriptEngineManager` constructor call.

Comment: Tried but still facing the same issue

Comment: I tried this it's working now. 
`val jsEngine = ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("rhino")` refer this [link](https://github.com/APISENSE/rhino-android)

Answer (score 2):

Your version of Java does not include a JavaScript engine. Java 8 includes the Nashorn javascript engine and has in general better support for Java <-> JavaScript interoperability. For older versions of Java you can put Rhino on the classpath and use that.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the module `jdk.scripting.nashorn` to the module graph?

```
java --add-modules jdk.scripting.nashorn
```