# Android Solve strings of mathematical expressions and put the result in TextView

Tags: javascript, java, android

i have this code:

```
uguale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String expression = "12+17";
        String result;
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        try {
            result = engine.eval(expression).toString();
            ResBar.setText(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ResBar.setText("error");
        }
    }
});
```

in my app always appears error, and never comes into try but always comes into catch, why?

Comment: what exception do you get? show us log

Comment: Use `e.printStackTrace()` to get the log of the error

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object javax.script.ScriptEngine.eval(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: @register_pippo "engine" variable is null , possibile duplicate , see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007787/why-does-getenginebyname-js-return-null

Comment: @an_droid_dev 
I could not find the answer

Comment: Since there is no `ScriptEngineManager` in the Android SDK, your problem presumably lies there. Talk to whoever supplied you with that class and ask them how to get a `"JavaScript"` script engine.

Comment: i included  import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptException;