# getEngineByName("JavaScript") returning null on Java 11

Tags: java, java-11, nashorn

I am trying to get my application running with java 11. Im building my own jre and have included the module `java.scripting` yet at runtime  this call

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
```

sets `engine` to `null`.

I know Nashorn is deprecated from Java 11 but it hasn't actually been removed so why am I getting this issue ?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55149056/1031296) help you in any way?

Comment: Not really because my code has not changed, I have just moved from running on Java 10 to Java 11

Comment: Which version do you use? More precisely, which distribution, which architecture,which JVM (J9 vs. Hotspot)? And which one was it before? On my machine, I checked it with Oracle 11 and AdoptOpen 12, in both cases, Nashoren was there …

Comment: Oracle java 10 Hotspot - > AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.6 Hotspot on Windows. Other change is I am using a cutdown runtime with jlink, do i need another module than java.scripting for Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding the module `jdk.scripting.nashorn` to the module graph?

```
java --add-modules jdk.scripting.nashorn
```

Can you try this?

Comment: Thankyou, that was the issue.

Comment: How to do that in eclipse?

Comment: Similar issue in android too, any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjdk.nashorn/nashorn-core
implementation group: 'org.openjdk.nashorn', name: 'nashorn-core', version: '15.4'
```

resolved my issue of `null` value of ScriptEngine