# Java returns cannont invoke ScriptEngine error

Tags: javascript, java, scriptengine

I am running Java's ScriptEngine class to run to some code. I use IntelliJ with maven dependencies when I run the code it says

```
Cannot invoke "javax.script.ScriptEngine.eval(String)" because "this.engine" is null
    at Run.Evaluater.<init>(Evaluater.java:19)
```

the code at line being the following

```
engine.put("event", event);
engine.put("content", message);
```

This is how I initiated the ScriptEngone

```
    public ScriptEngineManager man = new ScriptEngineManager();
    public ScriptEngine engine = man.getEngineByName("nashorn");
```

Comment: JDK 15 or later? It's gone. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8236933

Comment: Nope JDK 8 is the version I use, JRE 1.8 SE

Comment: Even then it says this.engine might be null. That's why I sent the place where instantiated the variable, so someone would be able to say if instantiation was wrong

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332640/getenginebynamenashorn-returns-null it looks like the no-args `ScriptEngineManager` constructor uses `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`. Specifying `null` as an argument bypasses anything weird the tccl might be doing, but still depends upon nashorn being present.

Comment: (As a rule, anything thread local is a bad idea. Inheritably thread local, even more so.)

Answer (score 1):

This error was encountered when a project was cloned from the code cloud when it was running. This part of the content is about the loading of the verification code. I did not understand the reason but it was a version problem. Change the JDK version from The problem is solved when 13 is reduced to 8.

Comment: Change to openjdk 8, worked for me. Thanks!